# Creating a web server to save scores online

Tags: php, html, server

I need to save scores from my game to an online database. I followed [this](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0321223659/files/Web_Lesson.pdf) tutorial (and a few others but they were almost exactly the same). Unfortunately, it didn't work when I tried to make it with 000webhost. You can see the error message [here](http://railfinder.000webhostapp.com/testing/scoresave.php?name=%22bob%22&score=%221%22).

[Here is a screenshot of the 000webhost databases page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C6H7.png)

This was the scoresave.php file that I made:

```
 <?PHP
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $score = $_POST['score'];
 $link = @mysql_connect("id3256303_scoretest", "id3256303_gamer1234", "gamer1234");
 if (mysql_errno()){
 exit("-2");
 }
 mysql_select_db('scoretest', $link);
 if (mysql_errno()){
 exit("-3");
 }
 $sql = "INSERT INTO scores(name, score) VALUES('$name', $score)";
 $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
 if (mysql_errno()){
 exit("-4");
 }
 exit("1");
?>
```

What have I done wrong? I followed the tutorial but it didn't work as expected. Please tell me what I need to fix.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injections. Where is your form?

Comment: The tutorial didn't say to make a form. I just went to this link http://railfinder.000webhostapp.com/testing/scoresave.php?name=%22bob%22&score=%221%22    That should have worked

Comment: Your POST global will always be empty if you don't POST anything to the server. Where else would the values come from?

Comment: The error messages you see when you access the PHP file are because there are no values from $_POST when you access the form directly. `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` probably means that the MySQL PHP module is not active on your server. You can use  `phpinfo();` to confirm.

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to activate the MySQL module on your web server.

Comment: Also, where do I need to put phpinfo();? How can I turn on the MySQL PHP Module if it isn't active?

Comment: @APAD1 How do I activate it then?

Comment: Find a newer tutorial - this code is both obsolete and pretty bad to start with... `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` I'm guessing your server is reasonably up-to-date (e.g. PHP7) in which case `mysql_connect()` doesn't exist.

Comment: @APAD1 `mysql_*` can't be activated on a modern web server; it's been killed off in PHP 7 - the extension no longer exists.